# WordPress database error on (fresh) reinstall

Tags: installation

I've done this many times before without problems. If I need to reinstall the Wordpress, I just drop all tables in the database from the *phpMyAdmin* and repeat the "famous 5-minute install" with a standard *wp-config.php* that doesn't contain something special. Because my old install was a development one, today I have started to reinstall the Wordpress with the *WP_DEBUG* changed to *true*, and when I have opened the *wp-admin/install.php* in my Firefox browser I have got this error:

> WordPress database error: [Table 'mydatabase.db_users' doesn't exist]
>   SELECT * FROM db_users WHERE user_login = 'myloginhere'
>
> WordPress database error: [Table 'mydatabase.db_users' doesn't exist]
>   SELECT * FROM db_users WHERE user_login = 'myloginhere'

If I change the  *WP_DEBUG* to *false* this error disapear. I deleted the browser cache, I changed the Unique Keys and Salts, but **my database/table name and the *user_login* name continue to apear** with the *WP_DEBUG* changed to *true*. **Where this information is saved**, if I have dropped the database tables? Why this happens if the install process is practically a fresh one and the user name has not yet been set for it?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the installation process, but I'd think to try a few things. To be clear, did you delete all of the files and use fresh ones as well, or are using the old site's files? If it's the latter, might want to see if there's anything in `wp-content/mu-plugins`. Failing that, I'd try deleting cookies for the domain, and deleting `wp-config.php` and letting WordPress create the file from scratch.

Comment: That was the problem! The cookies! Thank you very much! Post your comment as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: Huzzah! Glad that got hammered out right quick =] . Lemme do a little research to try and figure out why this happened and I'll throw an answer together... It's strange that it was cookies after all, considering that changing the salts would normally invalidate them. But I guess that cookie handling logic might not occur until after WordPress considers itself "installed"

Comment: Did your `wp_config.php` contain database information when you requested `install.php`?

Comment: Yes, `wp_config.php` contain database information when I requested `install.php`, but not my login info, that, as I think now, was read from the `cookies`.